# How do I extract exponent, modulus and finger print out of public key?

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I'm implementing an API in my C# project that needs public key for encryption.
the API needs exponent, modulus and finger print of public key and I have a public key like this: 
Slv8kg9qv2m6YHVQY3PjEw+QQtqSTXklHnIDAQAC 
How do I extract exponent, modulus and finger print out of this public key? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of public key is that? The base64 encoded string is only 30 bytes, equaling 240 bits, seems awfully small for a public key.

Comment: this is just an example for you guys to know what kind of encoding does it use, there is 4 more keys that this one is smaller than the others.